# What could cause entirely dark frames on a Fuji X100S?

Tags: troubleshooting, viewfinder, fujifilm-x100

I have a Fuji x100s and it's giving me headaches: the information overlay comes and goes, and the pictures I take are all black (see below). The EVF and LCD are black too.
The aperture works OK though, so does the shutter, and the camera seems to focus.

Any idea on what could be wrong? I bought the camera used.

[image].

Comment: Ok, stupid question, has to be got out of the way: when the frames are black, have you taken the lens cap off? And how are you seeing a _menu_ in the optical viewfinder? You can only see the menus if you use the EVF. Do you mean the information overlay? (and, by any chance, do you use polarized sunglasses?)

Comment: How are you using your camera? Can you change the aperture? Which mode are you using ?

Comment: Thanks! I was referring to the overlay. I edited for clarity. Sadly, no cap and no sunglasses...

Comment: I tried all different modes, played with ISO etc. I even tried to reset all settings.

Comment: Did this just start? Is it *always* all black? Can you post an example?

Comment: Yes it did just just start, and its always completely black. I've include an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick update, after sending the camera to be repaired: the main [PWB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board) had to be changed. It was about 100 $.

Comment: I'm guessing the PWB wasn't providing any voltage to the sensor, maybe?

Comment: I have the same problem, but have had issues with Fuji repair before, did you just send it in?

Comment: @Ryan I sent it in via an official repairer store and everything went smooth. I live in Italy and the repairer store took care of sending the camera to the Fuji center in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like everything on your camera is working except the sensor. For whatever reason the sensor seems to be outputting no image signal. You probably need to have a camera repair shop look at it and see if it can be repaired for less than the value of the camera. If the camera is new enough that it is still under warranty, you need to contact Fuji customer service about how to get it serviced under warranty.